# What type of pen do I need for my rabbit?

Tags: fence, pet-proofing

I have a simple question. I need a "fence" for for home-use, to put in safe my small pet (bunny) when I'm not at home. I would let him go free in his room but I want to protect him (and furnishings :P) so I am thinking to buy a small (plastic?) fences.

Comment: This might fit better on pets. SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plastic fences/pens are useless for rabbits. They'll chew right through them. What you need is a metal pet pen. You can get them at PetCo or most any pet store. Be sure to get one plenty tall enough as a determined rabbit can jump pretty high.

Comment: Yeah I did not figure out this before.. Is there a good online shop for buying this? I'm in Europe. Thanks btw for the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I can't speak for Europe. But I don't think it's anything special. Any online pet store should have them. Here's a link for PetCo in the US to get an idea of what the product is: http://www.petco.com/product/13904/Midwest-Black-E-Coat-Exercise-Pens.aspx?CoreCat=OnSiteSearch

Comment: you may want to consider a pen with a top or roof so predators cannot get into the pen and attack your bunny!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like a [*baby play yard*](http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=16055016&mr:keyword=&mr:trackingCode=942C8E66-7315-E311-A497-90E2BA285E75&mr:match=&mr:adType=pla&mr:filter=38524419286&cagpspn=plab_14136158&mr:referralID=NA&mr:ad=35201295886&mr:device=c&camp=PLAPPC-_-PID14136158&KPID=14136158) (also called *baby fence* or *baby gate*).

[image: baby fence]

Some of them are expandable and have adjustable footprints.

```
 Images and links provided as examples. Not an endorsment of any goods or source.
```

Comment: It is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for your advice!